# Unable to call watson language translator using proxy

Tags: nginx, ibm-watson, nginx-location, watson-assistant

when I called watson language translator service over a public network its responded with no error. meanwhile, its not able to get response body over my private network

I am using the NGINX has my load balancer and have configure a proxy_http for it on the configuration.

The error is

{ Error: Response not received. Body of error is HTTP ClientRequest object
    at formatError (root\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-core\lib\requestwrapper.js:115:17)
    at D:\Rafiki Project\production build\Rafiki Production Files 1\ecobot-orchestrator-master_23_9-orch_persistency_fixes\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-core\lib\requestwrapper.js:265:19
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

```
var languageTranslator = new LanguageTranslatorV2({
  username:'8******************',
  password:'*************',
  url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api/',
  version: '2017-05-26'
});

function translateToWSPLan(req, res, callback){
  console.log("the request for translation is::");
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req));
  console.log("======================");
  languageTranslator.identify(req.body.identifyParams, function(err, data){
    if(err){
      console.log('=================error==========');
      console.log(err);
      console.log('=================================');
      var errorLog = {name: err.name, message: err.message};
      callback(errorLog);
    }else {

    }
})
```

Comment: If the code above is working for the public network, then it is something with the configuration of your private network. Please share that configuration and other relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

See this issue raised on the Node.js SDK for Watson - https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/issues/900#issuecomment-509257669

To enable proxy routing, add proxy settings to the constructor

```
var languageTranslator = new LanguageTranslatorV2({
  username:'8******************',
  password:'*************',
  url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api/',
  version: '2017-05-26',
  // other params...
  proxy: '<some proxy config>',
  httpsAgent: '<or some https agent config>'
});
```

If you take a look at the issue, then there is a problem with accessing IAM tokens which does not work when there is a proxy, but as you appear to be using a userid / password combination, you should be OK. That is until cloud boundary style credentials are suspended and superseded by IAM credentials for all existing Watson services.